# Hibernate ManyToMany doesn't update

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Here's an example:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Book.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}
```

And in the other class :

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity= Reader.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "books")
@JoinTable(name="book_reader",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_reader",referencedColumnName="id_reader"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_book",referencedColumnName="id_book"))
public List<Reader> getReaders() {
    return readers;
}
```

I want to update new readers after saving a book. But it doesn't work.

```
book.setReaders(readers);
```

then

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(book);
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many-to-many , you need to set both way.

For ex

```
books.setReaders(readers);

for(Reader reader:readers)
    reader.getBooks().add(book);
```

and then update it will work.

Comment: I forgot that! Thanks so much!